# Section and Section Summary Preview

Tags: sectioning, draft, layout

I was wondering if there is a package or method to define sections in the format:

```
\section{Title}{My brief content description}
Full text...
```

Then using a switch like "Draft, Final, (Layout) " in which layout would only produce the section layout of the document with the summary of each section. I found solutions with variables and "if then" routines but that would clutter the files with more controls then maybe necessary.

I currently use a IEEEtran class but it would be good if it does not depend on the class:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts 

\begin{document}

\section{Sec 1}
- Some Description

Full Text

\subsection*{SubSec 1}
- Some Description

Full Text

\subsection*{SubSec 2}

etc.

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Well, why do you not show us a short compilable TeX code you have so far? Then we can see what you are doing and have not to guess (for example which document class you are using etc.) ...

Comment: You could create separate files and use `\input{file.tex}`. Then just comment them out as you go, and have the short description. When you want to see the whole document you would just comment the input.

Comment: Do you have news for us?

Comment: Hello Mensch, thanks for checking back, unfortunately not. The answers would work and reflect the general idea of what I am looking for. But this methods are rather impractical if there are numerous sections and subsections. Something that directly extends the sections commands would still be interesting. This would be quite useful when designing bigger documents.

Comment: Well, the problem is that the definition of section commands depends on the used class you did not tell us? That was the reason for me asking for an MWE ...

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question with a MWE

Comment: I suggest using the docstrip-package and adding docstrip-tags denoting "brief content description" and "full text". Then you can use docstrip's `\generate` for extracting/copying/combining portions of your .tex-input-files to other .tex-files as you like. This way you can, e.g., generate a file section-layout-summary.tex containing only sectioning-commands and summaries and then compile that for obtaining the pdf.

Comment: You wish an argument for denoting summaries. In case of "Layout": How to denote what belongs to "full text" and what doesn't belong to "full text"? I.e., how to precisely and reliably detect what shall be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

tI believe this could work, easy, orderly, and without any extra packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
Short description
%\input{intro.tex} % Done

\section{Stuff 1}
Short description
%\input{stuff1.tex} % Done

\section{Stuff 2}
Short description
\input{stuff2.tex} % Working on it

\end{document}
```